# React app not rendering on another pc from internet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's up friends?

I am programming an app using React. The page loads me perfectly from my pc and on my phone using a local ip, if I connect to my public IP from another computer the page goes blank, and apparently it stays in a loop of loading files 0.chunk. js or something similar and never renders the page.

I already configured HOST and IP in the .env file but I still have the same problem.

**UPDATE**

I dont know why, but deleted and reconfigure .env file and it works

Comment: Are you guys using the same WiFi?

Comment: I dont know why, but now it's working. Thank you by the way

Comment: I might be caused by a cache.

Comment: The problem comes back, now i get the white screen again